# Salesforce exactTarget endpoint call

Tags: java, salesforce

I want to make call to exactTarget API endpoint call from my java maven based application as follow:

```
Http h = new Http();


HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:value/send');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setBody("<jsonData>");

h.send(req);
```

But i am facing problem in making instance of `HttpRequest` and `Http`. Which library can i use to create instance of those classes?

Thank you